# Struggles in using multiple classes

Tags: java, eclipse, class

So currently, I'm struggling to make one particular program in eclipse for an assignment, while I am able to make most of the program, I seem to struggle with the no argument part of the program as well as bringing the pieces of the first class into the second for a brief moment. Here is my code for the first class

```
// Preparation of the input
import java.util.Scanner;

public class primarySetUp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Variable Declaration
    double userBagNumber;
    double userBagWeight;
    
    // Create Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
    
    // Opening Statement
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Coffee Sales Simulation!");
    
    // Get User Input
    System.out.println("How heavy do you want the bags to be?");
    userBagWeight = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("How many bags do you want?");
    userBagNumber = input.nextDouble();
    
    // Get output
    // Date
    System.out.println("Todays date:  ");
    System.out.printf("%tB %<te, %<tY", date);
    System.out.println(""); // spacer
    // Original Inputs
    System.out.printf("\nNumber of Bags: %3.0f", userBagNumber);
    System.out.printf("\nWeight of Each Bag: %3.2f", userBagWeight);
    System.out.print(" lbs");
    
    // Calling of the Class
    secondarySetUp mysecondarySetUp = new secondarySetUp(userBagWeight, userBagNumber);
    
    // End Program
    System.out.println("\nThank you for shopping with us!");
}

}
```

and here is my code for the second class, which is full of errors in this case.

```
public class secondarySetUp {
    
    // Constants
    static double pricePerPound = 5.99;
    static double taxRate = 0.0725;
    
    int singleBagger, pounderBagger;
    public secondarySetUp(double userBagWeight, double userBagNumber) {
    
        
        
        
    //  A method named getTaxRate() that returns the tax rate.  
        
        System.out.printf("\nPrice per Pound: $%2.2f", getPrice());
        System.out.printf("\nSales Tax: $%2.2f", getTaxRate());
        System.out.print(" %");
        System.out.printf("\nPrice of one bag weighing one pound: %3.2f", getSale());
        
    }
    // No argument pricing
    public Sale() {
            singleBagger = 1;
            pounderBagger = 1;
        }
    // First constructor receiving No argument pricing
    public Sale(int w, int n) {
            singleBagger = w;
            pounderBagger = n;
        }
    // Sale without tax
    public double getSale() {
        return userBagWeight * singleBagger * pounderBagger;
    }
    // Get Sale Tax
    public double getSaleTax() {
        return (getSale() * taxRate);
    }
    // Get total pricing
    public double getTotalPrice() {
        return (getSale() + getSaleTax());
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return pricePerPound;
    }
    public double getTaxRate() {
        return taxRate * 100;
    }
}
```

If you have any sort of fixes I could apply, please let me know; I am planning on adding the print statements for the rest of the arguments as well, but I'd like to get Sale() fixed up first.

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in `getSale()` where you are trying to use `userBagWeight`, but that variable doesn't exist outside the constructor parameters, which could create a lot of problems since other `methods` are calling on it. The constructor taking
`double userBagWeight, double userBagNumber`, yet it's not assigning them to any fields or doing anything with them.

I missed the part where you are treating `Sale()` as a `constructor`, but those are no `constructors`. The `constructor` is named after your class name.

```
public secondarySetUp(double userBagWeight, double userBagNumber)
```

change `Sale()` to `secondarySetUp` and you will be fine.

here how your class should be like :

```
public class secondarySetUp {

// Constants
static double pricePerPound = 5.99;
static double taxRate = 0.0725;

int singleBagger, pounderBagger;
double userBagWeight, userBagNumber;
public secondarySetUp(double userBagWeight, double userBagNumber) {
    this.userBagWeight = userBagWeight;
    this.userBagNumber = userBagNumber;

    singleBagger = 1;
    pounderBagger = 1;
    
    
    
//  A method named getTaxRate() that returns the tax rate.  
    
    System.out.printf("\nPrice per Pound: $%2.2f", getPrice());
    System.out.printf("\nSales Tax: $%2.2f", getTaxRate());
    System.out.print(" %");
    System.out.printf("\nPrice of one bag weighing one pound: %3.2f", getSale());
    
}
// First constructor receiving No argument pricing
public secondarySetUp(int w, int n) {
        singleBagger = w;
        pounderBagger = n;
    }
// Sale without tax
public double getSale() {
    return userBagWeight * singleBagger * pounderBagger;
}
// Get Sale Tax
public double getSaleTax() {
    return (getSale() * taxRate);
}
// Get total pricing
public double getTotalPrice() {
    return (getSale() + getSaleTax());
}
public double getPrice() {
    return pricePerPound;
}
public double getTaxRate() {
    return taxRate * 100;
}
```

}

`this` is a keyword to tell the program that we want to use the field "instance variable", if we have a method with `parameter` that have same name as a field name, then to tell them apart we tell the program `this.fieldName` to know which one we talking about.

Comment: So, what can I do in this case? I did try shifting them under the class that does have these included, yet that causes an error. What could I add or shift around to make it more viable?

Comment: you need to assign fields to them if you wanna use them in other methods beside the constructor. bellow your constants make a field for them `double userBagWeight;`
and in the constructor you do someting like this :
`public secondarySetUp(double userBagWeight, double userBagNumber) {
    this.userBagWeight = userBagWeight;`

Comment: It's simply giving me an error stating "userBagWeight cannot be resolved or is not a field" also, Sale() doesn't want to function in the slightest, where it states that the return type method is missing. What can I do for these errors?

Comment: check edit in answer

Comment: I'm still struggling to find why my errors are appearing like this, and I still haven't found where I'm supposed to put the this statement, here's my code for the new Sale() ' public double getSale(double userBagWeight) {
  return userBagWeight * singleBagger * pounderBagger;
 } ' errors like this appear "The method getSale(double) in the type secondarySetUp is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: check edit in the answer